# <h:inputSecret> becomes empty automatically even if i keep value in the back bean for it

Tags: java, xhtml, jsf-2

becomes empty automatically even if i keep value in the back bean for it.
I have already set the value for password in inputsecret variable in the back bean in jsf2 than also the input secret is being shown empty.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is indeed the default behaviour of [`<h:inputSecret>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/inputSecret.html) due to security reasons. You can get the value to redisplay anyway by setting the `redisplay` attribute to `true`.

```
<h:inputSecret value="#{bean.password}" redisplay="true" />
```

See also its [view declaration language documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/inputSecret.html) (emphasis mine)

> #### Encode Behavior
>
> Render the clientId of the component as the value of the "name" attribute. Render the current value of the component as the value of the "value" attribute, **if and only if the "redisplay" component attribute is the string "true"**. If the "styleClass" attribute is specified, render its value as the value of the "class" attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i was missing that tag

Comment: You're welcome. It's by the way an attribute, not a tag :)

Answer (score 1):

This is part of xhtml page:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputSecret value="#{login.password}" />
</h:form>
```

This is backing bean:

```
@Component //Spring component
public class Login{
    private String password;
    public Login(){
       password="12341fsf"; //any value you want to set
    }
}
```

I tested this code it works fine

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i am using the jsf managed bean, and it is not the case with it. Thanks again for reply